# remove users and groups from multiple groups using Remove-ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Also I freely admit that there are probably better more efficient ways to do what I'm doing here but my goal is to get this working and understand what I'm doing wrong so I'd appreciate corrections on my code instead of writing something from scratch if at all possible.

So here's my goal: I've got a list of groups in AD that all have similar name formats. I'm trying to create an array of those groups and remove any users who are not members of a specific group and any groups that are not members of a specific group.

For Example WAS-MyAdmins and NYC-MyAdmins are two group names. They have some users that should stay and may also have some groups that should stay. They also have users and groups that need to be removed. I swear I had this partially working earlier but I've tried a couple things and can't get back to that point.

When I run this it just deletes all the users and groups.

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "*-MyAdmins"' | Foreach-Object{ 
$Members1 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ | Where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | Get-ADUser -Properties * | Where {$members1.memberof -ne "CN=Tech_IDs,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com"}
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $Members1 -Confirm:$true}
$Members2 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ | Where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group'}| Get-ADGroup -Properties * | where {$Members2.memberof -ne "CN=Tech_Group,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com"}
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $Members1 -Confirm:$true
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "*-MyAdmins"' | Foreach-Object{ 
$Members1 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ | Where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | Get-ADUser -Properties * | Where {$_.memberof -notcontains "CN=Tech_IDs,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com"}
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $Members1 -Confirm:$true
$Members2 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ | Where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group'}| Get-ADGroup -Properties * | where {$_.memberof -notcontains "CN=Tech_Group,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com"}
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $Members1 -Confirm:$true}
```

Comment: Are you aware that the $Members1 line is inside the `ForEach-Object` scriptblock, and the $Members2 line is outside of the scriptblock?

Comment: Thanks @JamesQMurphy. I see that and have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are three main issues with your current code:

- The group removal is outside the `ForEach-Object` loop, so `$_` in `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_` isn't populated.
- You're using the variables `$members1` and `$members2` in the same expression whose result you assign to the respective variable. You probably meant to use `$_` in both cases.
- you compare the value of the `memberOf` property (an array) to a distinguished name (a string) using the equality operator (`-eq`). To check if an array contains a particular value you need to use the `-contains` operator instead.

Using the distinguished name for selecting items is the right idea, since it's one of the unique properties of AD objects. It's also one of the default properties of the objects that the AD cmdlets return, so it's practically always at your disposal. However, you're overcomplicating things. For instance, there's no need to handle users and groups separately.

To remove users and/or groups from an AD group when they're not member of particular other groups you'd first build a list of the distinguished names of the members of those other groups:

```
$groups = 'Tech_IDs', 'Tech_Group'
$dn = $groups | Get-ADGroupMember | Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName
```

With that list you can then filter the members of a given group:

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
           Where-Object { $dn -notcontains $_.DistinguishedName }
```

As a result you get a list of those group members that are supposed to be removed. Which then you do:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $members -Confirm:$false
```

Repeat the second and third step for all groups you need to process and you're done.

Comment: Thanks. I follow part of what you are saying and made a couple revisions. This looks like it is working but I'm still learning and not completely clear on the `$_` use.  Is it accurate that it changes along the pipeline? So at first it was the results of my initial query on line one but then it changed after the `Get-ADUser` and then `Get-ADGroup` commands? And if that's the case, why does it look like still refer to the group results in my `Remove-ADGroupMember` command. I'm not sure I follow your recommendation though. I don't have a list of users and groups. I need to pull them from AD?

Comment: `$_` is the "current object" variable, one of PowerShell's [automatic variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx). It always contains the most recent object that was retrieved from the pipeline. As for the users and groups: You said that you need to remove particular members from groups. How would you do that if you don't know beforhand which members must be removed?

Comment: I want to remove any user or group that is not a member of one of the two groups that are identified in my code, for example. `Where {$_.memberof -notcontains "CN=Tech_IDs,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com`

Comment: Then you need just the names of those two groups and invert the condition, so that members of those groups are not removed see updated answer.

Comment: I still don't think that gets me what I need unless your code is just partial. Where is your `$group` coming from? See the first line of mine. I have probably 40-50 groups this needs to run against which is why I was running the `$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "*-MyAdmins"'` and passing it into a `ForEach-Object` loop.  I think your tips helped me get mine working but I just wasn't clear on how the `$_ ` in the final line was referring to the objects in my initial `$Groups` variable.

Comment: Of course the code is just partial. I'm providing you with a blueprint, not building a machine for you. `$group` is a variable for whatever group you need to remove users from. Replace it with `$_` if you want to run the code in a pipeline.

Comment: Understood just making sure I wasn't missing anything. Thanks for your help.